# Python stopped working after quitting my local flask app

Tags: python, flask, localhost, command-prompt

I am new to web development with Python, and in fact web development in general... and only have a little more experience with python in general, so here goes. I am running `Python 2.7` as part of the `anaconda` package.

I have decided to give Flask a go, and got it up and running in `localhost:5000` through `virtualenv`. During this whole time python worked marvelously from my command prompt. After I closed the command prompt and re-opened, python will no longer run from command prompt, and says it is not recognized as an internal or external command. I checked my path variable, and it is still there. The only way I can get it to run is to be in the root `anaconda` folder. I tried running my app from there, and it seems to work, but when I route the browser to `localhost:5000`, i just see the `anaconda` launcher.

I'm thinking I didn't close out of my virtual enviroment correctly or something (I was still in it when I closed the command prompt). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you re-activate your virtual environment in your new command prompt?  (e. g. `cd your/project` and then `source virtual-env-folder/bin/activate`)?

Comment: I have now re-activated itand it didn't raise an error in the command prompt when I ran the page, but it won't load my page on localhost, and after deactivating it, the prompt still doesn't reconize the python command.